# Automate Input for Hidden Input Fields on ASPX Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vba

I am trying to automate the input to a website that uses the doPostBack menthod.  However, all of the inputs are "type=hidden."  Can these be accessed through automation using JavaScript or VBA, which I am using.  Does anyone have working example.  I've tried many ways using the getelementbyID, and some JavaScript functions to no avail.  I have seen similar questions like this, but I have not seen a definitive answer for accessing them for automation when you are not the site admin.

Comment: It would be easier to answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Using pure javascript, you can set the value of a hidden input element as follows:

```js
document.getElementById("hidden").value = "hidden value";
document.getElementById("text").value = "text value";
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="hidden" id="hidden" name="hidden">
  <input type="text" id="text" name="text">
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I would recommend though, that you look into using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) as this will simplify a lot of the tasks you might be implementing.

Comment: I am not sure if it is the dopostback method and encrypted viewstate associated with it that is complicating things, but I have tried setting the value like this, and it does not work.

Comment: Sounds like your element IDs are being generated by ASP.NET and you are referencing the field name.

Comment: I have been trying to access certain inputs by the IDs generated by ASP.NET.  I've used the inspect element feature in IE to pinpoint certain IDs, but so far, no luck automating them.